# Fresh Install Latest Version Of Kali, But Wi-Fi Unavailable

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux

I've installed the latest Kali Linux system from a bootable USB drive.

I'm using Lenovo Ideapad MIIX-300 10-IBY.

I've installed Kali before, there wasn't an error like this.

When I boot into my new system, the wi-fi shows up like this in the drop down menu:

[image]

And when I open the settings tab, there is an "Unavailable" expression under the title.

Here is the image.

[image]

Here are some outputs of some commands:

```
xenon@kali:~$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 52  bytes 2650 (2.5 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 52  bytes 2650 (2.5 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.42.233  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
    inet6 fe80::4407:71ff:fe99:8bb2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 46:07:71:99:8b:b2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 12900  bytes 7799556 (7.4 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 11567  bytes 2208000 (2.1 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


xenon@kali:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

usb0      no wireless extensions.

xenon@kali:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

I'm currently using my mobile internet package via tethering USB cable.

Thanks for your time.

### UPDATE !!!

When I enter command **lspci -nn | grep work** I get the following:

```
[ 1171.184702] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[ 1189.877509] rtl8723bs: acquire FW from file:rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin
[ 1189.877756] rtl8723bs mmc0:0001:1: firmware: failed to load rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin (-2)
[ 1189.877786] rtl8723bs mmc0:0001:1: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin failed with error -2
[ 1189.877803] Request firmware failed with error 0xfffffffe
[ 1189.895309] rtl8723bs: acquire FW from file:rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin
[ 1189.895433] rtl8723bs mmc0:0001:1: firmware: failed to load rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin (-2)
[ 1189.895458] rtl8723bs mmc0:0001:1: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin failed with error -2
[ 1189.895474] Request firmware failed with error 0xfffffffe
[ 1612.726049] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[ 1617.564234] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[ 1633.065256] rtl8723bs: acquire FW from file:rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin
[ 1633.065380] rtl8723bs mmc0:0001:1: firmware: failed to load rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin (-2)
[ 1633.065409] rtl8723bs mmc0:0001:1: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin failed with error -2
[ 1633.065426] Request firmware failed with error 0xfffffffe
```

I think this is the problem but I don't know how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: Edited the post, added important news. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

This generally happens when you just installed Kali Linux. Sometimes due to some errors or missing files, firmwares not getting downloaded by default, so we have to do it manually.

Open up your terminal.

```
1) sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

2) cd

3) sudo git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

4) cd linux-firmware

5) sudo make install

6) sudo reboot
```

This solved my problem, and now my Wi-Fi drivers and sound drivers etc. all set.

Good luck.